# Angular unit-testing spyOn service from component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I've got a login component and I want to test it whether it calls the service's method with proper values, however I don't know how to spy on that service from the component.

I've tried

```
beforeEach(() => {
...
authService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
});
```

And this is not working

```
it('should pass proper values', () => {
    const submitSpy = spyOn(authService, 'signInByLogin');
    const loginSpy = spyOn(component, 'signIn').and.callThrough();

    const username = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#username'));
    const password = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#password'));
    const submitBtn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('[type="submit"]'));

    username.nativeElement.value = 'test';
    password.nativeElement.value = 'password';

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(username.nativeElement.value).toBe('test');
    expect(password.nativeElement.value).toBe('password');
    expect(submitBtn).toBeTruthy();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    submitBtn.triggerEventHandler('click', null);

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(loginSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(submitSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test', 'password');
    });
});
```

It says

> An error was thrown in afterAll
>   Expected spy signInByLogin to have been called with [ 'test', 'password' ] but actual calls were [ '', '' ].

The service's method is called from the private function in login component.
And the call is

```
this.authService
            .signInByLogin(this.form.controls['login'].value, this.form.controls['password'].value).subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spying works fine. As you can see from the error message, the service is being called, but it's called with empty strings instead of the values of the input fields.

You change the value of the inputs, but you never emit any event, so Angular has no idea that the value has changed and this it must modify its model. You need to add something like

```
username.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event("imput));
```

(same for the other input of course).

Shameless plug: this wouldn't be necessary, and the code of the test would be more readable if you used [ngx-speculoos](https://ngx-speculoos.ninja-squad.com/).

Comment: I'm using `fixture.detectChanges()` and checking the values next lines, though

Comment: Yes, but change detection doesn't consist in finding changes in the DOM. It consists in finding changes in the model, and applying them to the DOM. The DOM is supposed to be modified by the user, and when the user enters something in an input, that triggers input events, and that's how Angular knows that something has been entered in the input. So if you don't fire any event in your test, Angular doesn't know that something has been entered.

Comment: Well, but why event 'click' on button triggers method from loginComponent? `expect(loginSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();` meanwhile on the button there is `[disabled]="form.invalid"`

Comment: Most probably because... the form is valid, and the button is thus not disabled. Note that I can only see the code of your test. Not the template nor the component.

Comment: I've just checked manually it's disabled when form is invalid. What's more interesting is that when I changed this click call to `submitBtn.nativeElement.click();` it stopped working when it's disabled (as expected). A bit strange behaviour

Comment: Probably not. But you haven't posted your code, so I can't say.